# Cast struct pointer to char* and copy

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code

```
struct Info { int age; char name[5]; }
char buffer[20];
Info i;
i.age = 10;
sprintf(i.name, "Case");
strncpy(buffer+5, (char*)&i, sizeof(Info));
```

Now I want to recover the record

```
Info j;
strncpy((char*)&j, buffer+5, sizeof(Info));
printf("%d %s", j.age, j.name);
```

However this prints empty string for name. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `strncpy` will stop when the string is `NULL` terminated.  Casting your struct to `char*` will not work with `strncpy`.  You could use `memcpy` instead.

Comment: Why 5? it should be `sizeof(Info)`

Comment: Why is `buffer` 10 bytes in size?  Why are you starting at `buffer + 5`?  Why are you only copying 5 bytes?

Comment: But the char[] follows exactly AFTER the int in the record, doesn't it?

Comment: This is very, very bad.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to tag this `C++`? This is pure `C`.

Comment: How many characters do you think `sprintf(i.name, "Casey");` copies, *including the null terminator*, into `i.name`?

Comment: sizeof(Info), obviously, I just typed it wrongly here.

Comment: @WhozCraig Well 5. '\0' will follow in the memory after i.name. Which will still be part of the struct, since the compiler will take 8 bytes for i.name, right?

Comment: "Which will still be part of the struct, since the compiler will take 8 bytes for i.name, right?" - and you RELY on this? Do you also start walking across the road without looking when the "Don't walk" sign has just come on because "the light is red for a little while after..." Both seems equally reasonable to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems with your copying mechanism:

1. You're assuming that `sizeof(Info)` is 5.  That's definitely not the case.
2. You're using `strncpy`, which is for strings.  `Info` is not a string, so you need to use `memcpy`.

The following will work:

```
char buffer[sizeof(i)];
memcpy(buffer, &i, sizeof(i));

...

memcpy(&j, buffer, sizeof(j));
```

---

There's also another problem; `name[5]` is not big enough to hold `"Casey"`, as that's 6 characters once you've accounted for the *null terminator*.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously it should be sizeof(i). However, I'm not sure I understand why strncpy wouldn't work here, since the char[] follows immediately after the int in the struct so there's no '\0' to make strncpy stop copying.

Comment: @user1377000: Firstly, it's just not good practice.  Secondly, what if one of the bytes in the int has a zero value?

Comment: OOh, the null characted is 0 in ASCII :)

Comment: It just occurred to me, after providing an answer with an assignment operator, that you can just assign normally in this case *without* writing an assignment operator. `Info` does not contain pointers, so default assignment operator and copy ctor will work just fine and do a deep copy. So instead of `memcpy(...)`, one can just do `j = i`.

Answer (score 4):

There's a few things:

- You're overflowing the buffer, `char name[5]` can't hold `"Casey"`, the terminator won't fit. This causes undefined behavior.
- You're copying from `&i` as if that was the pointer to a string, when in fact it points at a `struct` whose first field is an `int`. This won't work reliably.

Comment: +1, I'm afraid of what happens when `memcpy()` is discovered in the standard library. =P

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code you posted. First, the `name` field of `info` is too short considering that "Casey" must be null terminated.

The observation you made is due to another problem. The address of `j` will not be aligned with its `name` field. There is still an `int age` in that place, and most likely the `name` field starts 4 bytes later, but this is to the discretion of your compiler.

As for recovering `age`, that would not work because it was never stored to the buffer.

What could work is, assuming that `buffer` is large enough, to `memcpy(buffer, &i, sizeof(Info))` to store, and the first two arguments switched to reconstruct. Using `sizeof` helps here because this way you are asking the compiler how large the structure `Info` is given its way of layouting this structure in memory.

Comment: I think name (not age) is never stored in the buffer because (assuming age is 4 bytes) 3 bytes of age will be 0, which are ASCII for null, so strncpy will stop, right?

Comment: Sorry I misread. That's correct, except, to be precise, 0 is 0, independently of ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use memcpy() to copy `Info` variables. You can just use the assignment operator:

```
Info j;
j = i;
printf("%d %s", j.age, j.name);
```

You can do that because `Info` does not contain pointer member variables, and therefore you'll get a deep copy when using the assignment operator.  The same will happen if you just use the default copy constructor:

```
Info j(i);
```

or:

```
Info j = i;
```

Of course as pointed out by others, you should make `Info::name` large enough to hold the names you intent to store in it including the `'\0'` string terminator.